# Unable to parse values from a JSON file

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, parsing

**This is my python script:**

```
import json

with open('JSON_DataProvider.json', 'r') as file:
json_dict = json.load(file)

print (json_dict["office"][0]["medical"][0]["price"])
```

**Getting Below error after running the code**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/Project/@Python/open_json.py", line 7, in <module>
print (json_dict["office"][0]["medical"][0]["price"])
KeyError: 0
```

**And Here the json data i am using:**

```
{ "office": 
{"medical": [
  { "room-number": 100,
    "use": "reception",
    "sq-ft": 50,
    "price": 75
  },
  { "room-number": 101,
    "use": "waiting",
    "sq-ft": 250,
    "price": 75
  },
  { "room-number": 102,
    "use": "examination",
    "sq-ft": 125,
    "price": 150
  },
  { "room-number": 103,
    "use": "examination",
    "sq-ft": 125,
    "price": 150
  },
  { "room-number": 104,
    "use": "office",
    "sq-ft": 150,
    "price": 100
  }
]},
"parking": {
  "location": "premium",
  "style": "covered",
  "price": 750
}
```

}

Please help me to identify where i am doing wrong?

As i am trying to get the data from json file and feeding in our test automation script and that is nested json dataprovider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Exception is being thrown because you are trying to access a dictionary item with an index. Instead of `json_dict["office"][0]["medical"][0]["price"]` try `json_dict["office"]["medical"][0]["price"]`, that should work. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
print (json_dict["office"][0]["medical"][0]["price"])
```

To

```
print(json_dict["office"]["medical"][0]["price"])
```

Answer (score 0):

after trying to print out the `json_dict`, we could locate the problem.

`{'office': {'medical': [{'room-number': 100, 'use': 'reception', 'sq-ft': 50, 'price': 75}, {'room-number': 101, 'use': 'waiting', 'sq-ft': 250, 'price': 75}, {'room-number': 102, 'use': 'examination', 'sq-ft': 125, 'price': 150}, {'room-number': 103, 'use': 'examination', 'sq-ft': 125, 'price': 150}, {'room-number': 104, 'use': 'office', 'sq-ft': 150, 'price': 100}]}, 'parking': {'location': 'premium', 'style': 'covered', 'price': 750}}`

The correct way of doing this would be:
`json_dict["office"]["medical"][0]["price"]`

hope it helps!